# impedance matching between opamp and microcontroller (or Arduino)

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, impedance-matching

Based on my learning, Maximum power transfer theorem and Impedance matching, the output impedance and the input impedance of the components should be the same.  So does the output impedance of an op-amp (say LM741 which creates output based on a gain from sensor input) and the input impedance of micro controller (or Arduino) should be the same? Should we take the impedance values for design?

Please help. Thanks. 
(This is for my information only, not for any specific circuitry)

Comment: No, for feeding an ADC input, the goal is to maximize system Signal to Noise Ratio (SNR). There may be cases where impedance matching aids in accomplishing higher SNR and others where it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't **always** need impedance matching.

Generally it is only needed in **linear systems** where the inputs and outputs have a **characteristic impedance**.

This is usually only the case for RF (high frequency) signals and other cases where the **length** of a cable (or transmission line) is **much longer** than the **wavelength** of the signal.

Examples:

- The connection between an RF Power Amplifier (PA) to its antenna, this might work at 900 MHz, that's RF. You want all the power from the PA to arrive at the antenna so you **must** impedance match or power will be lost which is wasteful.
- The old landline telephone system. These have a 600 ohms characteristic impedance. Why? Because of the cables, these have a 600 ohms characteristic impedance so we drive the cable from a 600 ohm impedance and we also need to load it with 600 ohms. This prevents signal reflections and distortions. Land phone lines can be long so this is an issue even for low frequency signals like speech.

These above examples are both [transmission lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line).

Read that Wikipedia article and note how both ends of the T-line need to be terminated properly. That's the impedance matching.

Opamps do have a certain output impedance, like 10 ohms, but that is not a **characteristic impedance**. Most opamps are not designed to drive a similar value impedance. And it is not needed as we consider an opamp's output to be a **voltage source**. Also, we usually do not use an opamp to drive a transmission line nor do we use it at RF frequencies.

So no need for impedance matching with an opamp!

Unless you'd use a **very** long cable and want to use that as a transmission line and avoid signal reflections.

Similarly microControllers have **high impedance** inputs, these are not designed to take a signal from a transmission line. And we don't need that. The opamp will often be just a few centimeters away from the microController's input so no transmission line is needed.

Also, the **information** in the signal coming out of the opamp is a **voltage**, not a power, as long as that voltage arrives at the uC's input safely that's enough. There does not need to be any power matching.

Actually in the opamp to uC input case you have **maximum mismatch** but that's OK. The opamp has a **low** output impedance, the uC's input has a **high** input impedance. This is the best way to transfer a **voltage** while not wasting any power.

Answer (score 2):

When connecting a typical microcontroller's ADC input, the voltage source driving the input must either not budge when current is drawn from it, or must quickly stabilize once current is no longer being drawn from it.  Many microcontroller inputs have a nasty habit of sourcing or sinking significant amounts of current, in not-necessarily-predictable fashion, for a brief moment whenever they take a a reading.  If this causes the voltage on the pin to change, and if the voltage doesn't stabilize before the controller finishes sampling the input voltage, the controller will sample the glitched voltage rather than an accurate voltage.  In some cases, this may cause a 12-bit ADC to have 100 counts worth of uncertainty making it less useful than a quality 6-bit ADC.

I would guess that a 741 should probably stabilize quickly enough after a brief output spike to allow for reliable readings, but wouldn't rely upon such behavior without testing it--preferably while using an oscilloscope.